# Locally uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence in general

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

It is well known that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. I have checked on this page (see for example [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428214/an-example-of-a-locally-uniformly-convergent-sequence-which-does-not-converge-un) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51004/how-to-show-that-this-series-does-not-converge-uniformly-on-the-open-unit-disc)), that locally uniform convergence does not necessarily imply uniform convergence. So, I am wondering if locally uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence in general. Somehow it seems trivial, I still need to convince myself.

Here is what I thought: let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions defined on a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Assume there exists $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f_n\to f$ locally uniformly on $A$. (*) Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $A$. Then $f_n\to f$ pointwise on every compact subset of $A$. Does it imply that $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $A$?

**Edit**: After having read the comments: [...] (*) Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $A$. Let $x \in A$ be given. Then $\{x\}$ is a compact subset of $A$. Then $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $\{x\}$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $f_n\to f$ pointwise for all $x\in A$.

But this is still inconsistent. See my comment below.

Comment: For each $x\in A$, $\{x\}$ is a compact subset of $A$...

Comment: @Max So the answer is "yes"? An infinite unions of compact sets is not compact. It is not known if $A$ is compact or not.

Comment: as $\{x\}$ is compact we have uniform convergence on that set and so in particular pointwise convergence.

Comment: @JonasLenz I have edited my post. How does my reason sound?

Comment: @Hopeless sounds gut

Comment: @JonasLenz Hold on a moment. Before reaching to the conclusion, one would have: "Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $A$. Let $x \in A$ be given. Then $\{x\}$ is a compact subset of $A$. Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\{x\}$, and so $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A$, since $x$ is arbitrary." But is this not a contradiction, because locally uniform convergence does not imply uniform convergence in general?

Comment: The part and so $f_n\to f$ uniformly on A is false.